# how to get the value on form input in cakephp

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I have:

```
echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label' => 'Username: '));
```

equivalent to  in traditional php coding..

how can I get the value inputted in that textbox like when you do $val = $_POST['username']; in traditional php coding.

I need this for login validation. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get it

```
$val = $this->data['ModelName']['username']; //CakePHP 1.X.X

//or

$this->request->data['ModelName']['username']); //CakePHP 2.X.X
```

Where "ModelName" is your currently assigned model to form.

Update:

```
$user = $this->Account->find('first', array(
   'conditions' => array(
      'username' => 'user1'
   )
));
```

Comment: thank you very much! Oh! I'm so noob. haha! anyways, how can you do a select statement with where with cakephp. for example. "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = 'user1'";

Comment: anyways what "first" suppose to mean?

Comment: Pleas read more about http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Answer (score 0):

From CakePHP 4.x, you should use

```
$this->request->getData()
```

For example

```
$title = $this->request->getData('title');
```

If the data are nested (ie, specifying a model), use a dot notation

```
$userName = $this->request->getData('user.name');
```